# unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, ggts

i had installed the spring security plugin in my application but now i am getting the below error

unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

Comment: What version of Grails are you using and what version of the Spring Security plugin did you install?

Comment: i am using grails-2.4.4 and spring-security-core:1.2.7.3

Comment: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html  The following deprecated classes have been removed from Grails 2.4.x:

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder If you or any plugins you have installed are using these classes you will get a compilation error. The problem can be rectified by updating to new plugins and using grails.util.Holders instead.

Comment: But vahid that link shows step of upgradation from 2.3.x to 2.4. but i am already using grails-2.4.4 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the problem: 
i just uninstalled the old version of spring plugin which i was using(spring-security-core:1.2.7.3)

then i fire these 2 command:

grails clean

grails refresh-dependencies

Then i installed the spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 plugin

that worked

Answer (score 5):

Vahid is right..

try to change your grailsApplication to Holders.grailsApplication 
and one more thing..
pluginManager to Holders.pluginManager

It should work!

Comment: How do we change `grailsApplication`? should we add it in `Bootstrap.groovy`?